# Shipping in Magento and Google Checkout based on location

Tags: magento, google-checkout, android-pay

I integrate Google Checkout into Magento store (1.7.0.2). And i have one big problem.

I want to charge costumers for shipping based on their location.

**For example**: UK shipping: Free / EU shipping: 7 euro / WORLD shipping: 12 euro

Now when i click on Google Checkout button it sends me to pay but its not shipping costs added in order..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Magento user/dev so this answer is specific to Google Checkout API.

Based on your question, you can send shipping information to Google:

1. As flat rate (pre-calculated on your end) data

   - note that `flat rate` is just Google speak - it simply means you/merchant have (pre)determined the cost some way and Google doesn't do any additional work with it (no other calculation, callback, etc.).
   - You can combine this "pre-calcuated" rate with [shipping/address restrictions](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Flat_Rate_Shipping#XML_Example_2) so that only the appropriate rate is displayed to your customer based on what `delivery address` they provide on checkout- remember, your customers can create new delivery addresses and/or select any they have provided previously, at the Google Checkout site. This simply means that the only time a delivery address is determined is **at the Google Checkout web site**.
   - additional reference - [geographic areas](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Understanding_Areas)
2. Use [Merchant Calculations Shipping](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Merchant_Calculated_Shipping)

You can't really use account shipping settings based on your question because it only handles the default Google restriction where *delivery is restricted to your account country*. In order to  "enable" international delivery, you'll have to do this in HTML/XML code.

As stated, I'm not a Magento user/dev so how to do this in Magento isn't something I can help you with....

Hth...